# Angular Material: clicking item in mat-sidenav should change content in mat-sidenav-content

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, frontend

I need to implement menu similar to nav menu in angular docs page: https://angular.io/tutorial/ .

Menu is on the left side, clicking each item will change content showing in `mat-sidenav-content` - it will show registration page, users list , etc. - depending on which link was clicked. But menu has to be available all the time.

Now I have something like this:
[image]

How to achieve that if I for example click on registration link - registration page will be shown in content bar and so on with other buttons?

Comment: Can you post your code or a stackblitz of your code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, you should wrap you left panel in routing (add new outlet), and modify your component with panel, create service or helper with array of links for each route.
And then listen Route, and select array of links.

Or you can pass data to your route configuration

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch : 'full'},
  {path : 'registration', component : LeftPanelComponent, data : {some_data : 'some value'}, outlet: "aside"}
];
```

Here is a good example : [Router Outlet](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-router-nested-routes-and-nested-auxiliary-routes-build-a-menu-navigation-system/)
The link in left panel should be routerLink)

Comment: Thank you. But when I click link in the left panel - which click handler should I attach there? Can you please provide some example?